# Is it possible to conduct a Chi-Square Test to determine the distribution of a binary uniform distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, uniform-distribution, discrete-data, discrete-distributions

Suppose a data with a large sample size has a binary categoric variable (i.e. True/False, etc) and it is assumed that the null hypothesis of the sample follows a discrete uniform distribution.

Is it possible to conduct a Chi-Squared test to determine whether or not the data follows a uniform distribution (and therefore the data can be statistically proven to have an equal amount with no significant difference)?

If not, explain the reason and give an alternative.

Any help would be appreciated, as well as any criticism regarding the wording of my question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "the null hypothesis ... follows a discrete uniform distribution"?  That's too vague to determine what you're trying to ask.  Be mathematically explicit.

Comment: @whuber Let's say a data with 2000 samples are taken from a health survey regarding smoking. The sample consists of people who smoked and who doesn't, and someone wants to make an analysis under one condition; the amount of smokers are the same as the non-smokers (1000 smokers and 1000 non smokers ideally). However, the sample that's given isn't exactly that number, rather it's off by a few (let's say 975 smokers, while there rest are non-smokers). That person wants to show that even though it's not equal, it still follows the ideal uniform distribution by a significance level of alpha.

Comment: @whuber I hope that explains your question, pardon me if I'm not able to explain clearly

Comment: I can't make much sense of that.  It sounds like you want to perform a standard test of proportions to see whether the population has 50% smokers.  I cannot discern any kind of "discrete uniform distribution."

Comment: @whuber In that case, what I wanted to say was that I just wanted to see if I could make a Goodness-of-Fit test to a data that follows of a uniform distribution, only in this case, it deals with a binary categoric variable. Again, sorry if I make this too complicated than it already seems

Comment: It is sounding *way* more complicated than it need be.  I still don't understand what "follows a uniform distribution" might mean.  These data that you describe will follow a *Binomial* distribution, not a uniform one.

Comment: @whuber Oh my you're correct, that's the one I'm looking for. Well in that case, what test should I do if i wanted to prove that my data follows the binomial distribution?

Comment: A one-sample test of proportions.

Comment: @whuber That answers my question, so thank you very much for the help!